# Update a column in the most recent record within a partition/group

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by, partition

Greetings and Happy holidays!

I am a newbie in SQL and I am trying to solve a problem. I googled but could not find the solution. If this is in a wrong forum, I request you to move it to appropriate forum.

Thanks in advance for any insights you may give me! Appreciate it!

**My Table:**

```
ID1        ID2 RECNBR ACTFLG                    
ABDCDDFDD  1   1      0                 
JHKLLLKHJ  9   1      0                
SDFKJLSDK  4   1      0              
LKJHJNHGJ  9   2      1 <-- Error (only the record with highest RECNBR for a ID2 can have ACTFLG as 1                     
SDFDSLLSD  2   1      0               
BDFDFDFDD  1   2      1                    
DSFKLKJSD  4   2      1            
LOKKJLLLH  9   3      1           
GFLDSFFGL  2   2      1
```

**Few Facts:**

1. ID1 is an unique Alphanumeric column which is unique for each record.
2. ID2 Numeric values but not necessarily in sorted order.
3. RECNBR - Starts with 1 for each ID2 and increments by 1 for each new record for the same ID2.
4. ACTFLG - This field is set the '1' for the highest RECNBR within the same ID2. All other records should have zero.
5. Records are not in any sorted order.

**Issue:**

1. If you notice the ID2 '9'. It has 3 records with RECNUM 1, 2 and 3. As per facts only RECNUM '3' can have a ACTFLG of '1'. However in my table, I have both RECNUM '2' and also '3' with ACTFLG '1'.

**Requirement:**

Note: I am trying to avoid loops. I have a solution using loops and it is taking lot of time to execute. I am trying to see if I can do this with some simple 1 or 2 line code using system functions such as PARTITION/GROUP BY etc.

I can set ACTFLG to '0' for all records. I need coding ideas on how to identify the record with highest RECNUM with in a particular ID2. Once identified I want to update the ACTFLG to '1' for those records.

OR

Identify records such as ID2 '9', RECNUM '2' (which has issue) and update the ACTFLG to '0'.

Comment: Which is it: sql-server or mysql? Please remove the tag that isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server, here's the hammer:

```
with cte as (
   select *, row_number() over (partition by ID2 order by recnbr desc) as rn
)
update cte
set actflg = case when rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end;
```

Here's the scalpel:

```
with cte as (
   select *, row_number() over (partition by ID2 order by recnbr desc) as rn
)
update cte
set actflg = 1
where rn = 1
   and actflg = 0;

with cte as (
   select *, row_number() over (partition by ID2 order by recnbr desc) as rn
)
update cte
set actflg = 0
where rn <> 1
   and actflg = 1;
```

Regardless of which approach you take, you should only have to do this as a one-time cleanup. Going forward, best to maintain the value correctly.

You didn't ask for it, but a couple of observations on the design:

1. If only one item can be active per ID2 group, enforce that with a unique filtered index. Something like `create unique index [myFilteredIndex] on [myTable] (ID2) where (actflg = 1);`
2. The actflg is redundant insofar as given the other information in the table, I can derive the value for actflg for any row. I will concede that storing it in row may be a performance optimization, but it does come with the overhead of having to maintain it (as the whole raison d'être of this question would suggest). It's worth playing around with deriving which is the active one on the fly and dropping this column entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This basic solution should work: (now with T-SQL syntax)

```
update MyTable
set ACTFLG = 0 ;

update MyTable 
set ACTFLG = 1
from MyTable AS T1
where T1.RECNBR = (
  select MAX(T2.RECNBR) 
  from MYTable as T2
  where T1.ID2 = T2.ID2);
```

Here it is working in a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f47b8/2